# SVG viewbox and scrolling on the y-axis

Tags: svg, viewbox

I have a huge svg 3200*1800. I only want to show a part of that image something like 400*1000,  ensuring that the width is the dominant attribute and having a scroll bar for the height but when I set viewbox it increase the width to display the added height.

```
   viewBox="900 550 400 1000"
```

Is their a way to stop this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked it out you need to increase the height relative to the viewbox for example I ended up with something like this:

```
width="1400"
height="4000"
viewBox="966 555 350 1000"
```

Compared to what I used to have:

```
width="350"
height="1000"
viewBox="966 555 350 1000"
```

Answer (score 1):

You just set 'preserveAspectRatio' to "none" along with your 'viewBox' attribute, then your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

This answer builds on Shane's answer (which does not cater to variable window sizes)...

To have width-dominant overflows:

1. Let the 'viewbox' define the portion of the graphic to display (any **known** aspect ratio)
2. Let the svg element have default width and height (100%)
3. With javascript, dynamically set the height of the svg element every time the window resizes

The code below works for my [learning project](https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/freshcode_public/learn/svg/src/main/webapp/render/index.jsp) and is NOT production code.

In the head element:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    var svgRatio = ${viewboxRatio}; // ratio must be known

    // From http://stackoverflow.com/a/13651455
    if(window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent('onresize', resizeSvg);
    }
    else if(window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('resize', resizeSvg, true);
    }
    else {
        //The browser does not support Javascript event binding
    }

    function resizeSvg() {
        var height = window.innerWidth * svgRatio;
        var svg  = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
        svg.setAttribute("height", height.toString());
    }
</script>
```

At the end of the body:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    resizeSvg();
</script>
```