# How can I attach a window resize event listener in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, plugins

I'm making a JS/PHP plugin for distribution. I want it to be as easy to install as this:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Testing my Plugin</TITLE>
<?php
  include 'path/to/myPlugin.php';
  echo getMyPluginHeadContent();
?>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<?php
  echo getMyPluginContent("Arguments will go here");
?>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

However, I want this plugin to attach a window resize listener **without** overriding `window.onresize`, in case there are any other scripts that also require the use of that method. **Is there any javascript command like `document.addEventListener("resize", myResizeMethod, true);`?** I know that's not it, because that's not working, and the MDN and W3C are very vague about what arguments `addEventListener` takes.

**I do not want an answer telling me to use `window.onresize = myResizeMethod` or `<BODY ONRESIZE="myResizeMethod">`, as these are not as plugin-friendly.**

Comment: Since you are trying to add this to the window, have you tried `window.addEventListener`?

Comment: Pretty much any <element>.on<event> = <function> can be turned into a <element>.addEventListener(<event>, <function>)

Comment: @bhamlin : Insightful comment, thank you.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Since you are trying to call this function on the resize of the window, you will want to bind the function to the window and not to the document.  To support versions of IE that are less than 9, you will want to use `attachEvent`.  Please note that `attachEvent` requires you to specify the `on` keyword.  Here is an example:

```
if(window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onresize', function() {
        alert('attachEvent - resize');
    });
}
else if(window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
        console.log('addEventListener - resize');
    }, true);
}
else {
    //The browser does not support Javascript event binding
}
```

Similarly, you can remove events in the same way.  When using `removeEventListener`, make sure that you pass the same value of `useCapture` as you did when calling `addEventListener`.  This is the third parameter which is the `true/false` value.

```
if(window.detachEvent) {
    window.detachEvent('onresize', theFunction);
}
else if(window.removeEventListener) {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', theFunction, true);
}
else {
    //The browser does not support Javascript event binding
}
```

Comment: Other than forgetting a `);` in your example code, this is perfect! Thank you!

Comment: @Supuhstar Oops, fixed the code.  Glad you were able to get it working.

Comment: I've taken to putting this in the `else`: `var oldresize = window.onresize; window.onresize = function() { if(oldresize) oldresize(); /* My code here... */ }`. Then to detatch it, I do `window.onload = oldload;`.

Comment: @Supuhstar I'm confused as to why you are doing that.  `attachEvent` and `addEventListener` keep the order of functions bound to them.  To detach, you just need to use the correct function with the function as the argument.  Just remember that your function must be stored in a variable `var myFunc = ...` to ensure that the memory address is the same to unbind.

Comment: This also keeps order, and I only use it if `attachEvent` and `addEventListener` are both unavailable.

Comment: @Supuhstar I hope that you never come across a browser that is lacking that support (those would be very old browsers), but I am glad that you have a workaround for it.

Comment: Since the `window.addEventListener('resize', ... , true);` is `true` for the `useCapture` parameter, the method `window.removeEventListener('resize', theFunction);` requires a `true` in order to work properly. `window.removeEventListener('resize', theFunction, true);`

Comment: @DiegoMariano Thank you for pointing that out.  Yes, the `useCapture` should be the same and the default assumption is `false` if not specified.  I have updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Is there any reason (besides that it was what OP used) that this answer has `useCapture` of `true` instead of relying upon the default value of `false`?

Comment: @rinogo In the example, `true` was supplied to the `addEventListener` function.  To remove that listener, the `useCapture` must match what was supplied when you registered.  Here's the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) on that

Answer (score 33):

You don't resize the document but the window. This works :

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function(){console.log('resize!')}, true);
```

Comment: As an addition to this, you will want to use `attachEvent` for versions of IE < 9.

Comment: @Kyle I didn't knew that (my sites are either not IE8 compatible or jquery based). Feel free to build your own answer. I see in your comment that you knew for window vs document too.

Comment: This is trigger more than one in IE 8. I couldnt find why that happens.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend `ResizeObserver`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver

Example of use:

```js
const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(e => {
    console.log(e);
});

resizeObserver.observe(document.body);
```