# javascript: get height of div and use it in other div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to use javascript to get the height of a responsive div, and use the output in another div.
But I'm no good in javascript at all...

So far I've come up with:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var offsetHeight = document.getElementById("myDiv").offsetHeight;
var curr_width = parseInt(offsetHeight.style.height); 
offsetHeight.style.height = (offsetHeight);
</script>

<div id="mydiv"></div>
<div id="offsetHeight" style="top:0px"></div>
```

So what I want is that when I resize the document, the height of `mydiv` is used for the `style="top"` value...

Anyone who can help me out? Would be wonderful!

Comment: Use your Script after DOM is loaded...If there is no element which is loaded, how will you read property of the element..? Could you find any error in console ?

Comment: No, I'm just not good enough in javascript.. I have made a wonderfull responsive cross-fade header with only css. But the problem is that I cannot place a div under the header. The header height is absolute (I need the absolute for the crossfade). So I need the height of the header for the top value of my content header. But I just don't know enough of javascript to figure out how to do that. Been searching now for several days...

Comment: place your script before closing `</body>` tag..And while setting height, it should be `offsetHeight+'px'`

Comment: I did like Rayon suggested, but no result yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You must be careful about upper/lower letter (`mydiv` -> `myDiv`)
2. You need to add `px` to set a element's height

```js
var offsetHeight = document.getElementById("mydiv").offsetHeight;
document.getElementById("offsetHeight").style.height = offsetHeight + 'px';
```

```css
#mydiv {
  background:red;
  height:150px;
}

#offsetHeight {
  background:green;  
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<div id="offsetHeight" style="top:0px"></div>
```

**Important** The script code should be before `</body>` or wrap it with the listener [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded#Example)

Comment: Key point here is placing script before closing `body` tag or using `DOMContentLoaded` or `window.onload`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I assumes he knows it already but I was added this to the answer

Comment: I'm glad to hear. If this works for you please accept the answer so it will help to other people. Good luck..

Comment: works, but I need it to get the height of a responsive image with an auto height. And it the height changes when the browser is resised. So I tried this: var offsetHeight = document.getElementById("figure img").offsetHeight;, but no result. Should I add an "onResize" or something?

Comment: Yes, exactly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651274/how-can-i-attach-a-window-resize-event-listener-in-javascript#13651455

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery and let the document load. write your logic inside:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //code here    
});
```

[Answer here](https://jsfiddle.net/deepak1197/04wg05a6/)

Comment: You can suggest the equivalent way `DOMContentLoaded`.

Answer (score 0):

try with this below code it may help you

```js
var mydivHeight = document.getElementById("mydiv").offsetHeight;
document.getElementById("offsetHeight").style.height = mydivHeight + 'px';
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">mydiv</div>
<div id="offsetHeight" style="top:0px"></div>
```