# reload an javascript animation when resize the window

Tags: javascript, html

I did a javascript animation in 3D with three.js and I want reload the page or the animation when I resize the window, so tried that:

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
    window.location.reload(true);
});
```

but it's didn't work... I need help

( I am a beginner in javascript)

Comment: It's not clear what you're really trying to do. Pretty much [all of the three.js examples](http://threejs.org/examples) support resizing so if you just want to handle resizing look at source of any of those examples.

Comment: I removed the webgl and three.js tags since the answer you accepted had absolutely nothing to do with either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to call this function on the resize of the window, you will want to bind the function to the window and not to the document.  To support versions of IE that are less than 9, you will want to use `attachEvent`.  Please note that `attachEvent` requires you to specify the `on` keyword.  Here is an example:

P.s.: If you want to exact answer you should give more information about your browser and version.

```
if(window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onresize', function() {
        alert('attachEvent - resize');
    });
}
else if(window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
        console.log('addEventListener - resize');
    }, true);
}
else {
    //The browser does not support Javascript event binding
}
```

Similarly, you can remove events in the same way

```
if(window.detachEvent) {
    window.detachEvent('onresize', theFunction);
}
else if(window.removeEventListener) {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', theFunction);
}
else {
    //The browser does not support Javascript event binding
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13651455/6035082)

Page reloading doesn't same for all browser. Because of that you should look these page reloading examples also.
Javascript 1.0

```
window.location.href = window.location.pathname + window.location.search + window.location.hash;
// creates a history entry
```

Javascript 1.1

```
window.location.replace(window.location.pathname + window.location.search + window.location.hash);
// does not create a history entry
```

Javascript 1.2

```
window.location.reload(false); 
// If we needed to pull the document from
//  the web-server again (such as where the document contents
//  change dynamically) we would pass the argument as 'true'.
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3715123/6035082)

Comment: window.location.replace(window.location.pathname + window.location.search + window.location.hash); work very well on chrome and firefox, thank you very much

Comment: @sami54 Glad to hear my answer is useful for you

Comment: Since the question is about `WebGL` IE9 arguably has no relevance since IE9 doesn't support WebGL

Comment: That's not the point. The point is your answer is irrelvant to all browsers that support WebGL. All browsers that support WebGL are auto-updated. On on top of that all of them support all the latest JavaScript and HTML5. There's zero reason to check for JavaScript 1.1 or 1.2 or attachEvent on any browser that supports WebGL

Comment: You're missing the point. Your answer works. It's just full of extraneous info that obfusicates your solution. There's no reason to worry about JavaScript 1.1 or 1.2 or attachEvent because the person is using WebGL so by definition they aren't targeting IE or old JavaScript

Comment: @gman if you look sami54 comment for this answer, you can see JavaScript 1.1 solution is work for he. Anyway, I didn't take main point WebGL browsers have to use latest version of javascript. I have just focused location.reload is not work for any browser that's means browser have lower version of javascript.

Comment: Find, then I'll remove the WebGL and three.js tags

Comment: I didn't mean that this question related to WebGL and three.js. He asked location.reload does not work with my browser. Because of that I give different answer that is uncommonly used for location.reload. And this answer work. I didn't understand why you give down vote to my post.