# Remove all functions in window.resize

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I would like to stop some script working on window resize and replacing it by mine.

The problem is I can't get name of function from script mentioned above. So is there some way to remove all of that WITHOUT USING JQUERY ON IE8? (event listeners does not work).

Comment: `window.onresize = null` to remove resize handler or/and `window.onresize = function(){ /*custom code */ }` to set own one

Comment: If the handler was added using `attachEvent`, then no.

Answer (score 0):

Just override it:

```
window.onresize = function () { 
   // your code
};
```

### Edit:

I suppose the issue is linked to IE version...

Try that :

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // your code
});
```

### Update

See for IE8 :

```
window.attachEvent("resize", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // your code
});
```

Comment: It is weird. Be sure you are overriding it after the unwanted events are set!

Comment: I know, I even tried to insert your code into interval, but it does nothing :(

Comment: Copy/paste the code from my answer in the IE8 console please, then resize.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133322/discussion-between-alteyss-and-arkadiusz).

Comment: addEventListener does not work on ie8, furthermore I shuld know name of exact function I want to turn off, but I don't. Is there possibility to get full list of functions? All the time I have been googling "list of functions window.onresize" I get list of actions like onclick, onresize ect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full answer with a support for IE < 9:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13651455/3774114

```
window.attachEvent('onresize', function() {
        alert('attachEvent - resize');
    });
}
else if(window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
        console.log('addEventListener - resize');
    }, true);
}
else {
    //The browser does not support Javascript event binding
}
```

Similarly, you can remove events in the same way

```
if(window.detachEvent) {
    window.detachEvent('onresize', theFunction);
}
else if(window.removeEventListener) {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', theFunction);
}
else {
    //The browser does not support Javascript event binding
}
```

Comment: the point is I can't get the name of the function I want to remove.

Comment: I have found your exact code on mozilla's page and it does not work on ie8